# OpenMP segmentation fault when parallelising a for loop with nested while loop

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a for loop which will sum up two variables, 'Time' and 'successRuns' but the number of times the loop is going to run is changed inside the loop randomly. (I think the code is self-explaining on this matter)

Problem is I keep getting segmentation fault error. This does not happen when not using openmp.

This is the loop I'm trying to run in parallel.

rnd() is a function that returns a random number between 0 & 1.

```
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(w=1; w<=200000; w++){
        tau=0;
        for(i=0; i<N; i++) g[i]=1;
        g[0] = 2;
        N_a=N-1;
        N_b=1;
        b=false;
        while(b== false){
            tau++;
            R = rnd() * (N_a + N_b*r_b);    
            prev=0; next=0;
            chosenB = N;
            for(i=0; i<N; i++){
                if(g[i]==1) next = prev + 1.0;
                    else next = prev + r_b;
                if(R>prev && R<next){
                    chosenB = i; break;
                }
                prev = next;
            }
            R = rnd() * N;
            while(int(R)==chosenB)
                R = rnd() * N;      
            if(g[int(R)]==1) N_a--;
                else N_b--;
            g[int(R)] = g[chosenB];     
            if(g[chosenB] == 1) N_a++;
                else N_b++;
            if(N_b == N){
                b = true; break;
            }
            if(N_b == 0){
                b = false; break;
            }
        }
        if(g[0]==2 && b==true){     
            Time += tau;
            successRuns++;
        }
        if(b==false) w--;
        runs++;
    }
    //end of parallel
    cout<<Time/successRuns<<endl;
    cout<<successRuns/runs<<endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems that all variables are shared/ visible between the threads.

Because of that, unfortunately is impossible to predict what is happening in the execution of your code, due to the parallel race condition.

Race condition is when the executing threads are in diferent parts of the code, changing variable values when you wouldn't want it. Causing a unpredictable result.

for example:

```
int main(){
    int var=0;    //shared variable, visible to all threads

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int myOnly;    //private variable, each thread have it's own
        if ( var <= 0)
            var++;
        else
            var--;

        myOnly = var;
        printf("private variable: %d\n",myOnly);
    }
    printf("value : %d", var);
}
```

Let's supose that we have 2 running threads here, if the first thread executes the `if()` cheking and reachs `var++` before the second thread executes the `if()` cheking,the second thread will enter the `else` code ( instead of the `if` ).

But if the second thread check the `if()` statement before the first one alters the value of `var`, it will execute `var++;`, not `var--;`.

That way the value of myOnly can be -1 or 1 for both on only one thread ,depending on what happened.

And how do we know wich one of them will happen? We don't.
Each thread is running independent, there's no way to predict what will happen.

For this there are the  `#pragma omp barrier` and others parallel synching tools, but they are very costfull.

Try to organize the variables and create local ( private ) one’s to the threads, so then there’s no chance to one thread overwrite something that it shouldn’t.

Comment: http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-data.html in this guide it stated that when variables are set and used each time in each iteration it makes them private. Is it wrong? should I use private(i,fixed,g,...) and list all my variables?

Comment: Well, this guide says that if the variable are declared outside from from #pragma omp parallel scope, it is shared, and inside is private. I will edit my answer explaining better.

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake. Now I declared the variables inside the for loop and the error is gone and the code seems to be running OK. But it runs very slow compared to when not using OpenMP

Comment: @Alireza, how many threads are you running?
and how are you counting the time?

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. 2 threads at the moment but I'm going to run it on a 8 threaded cpu later. This piece of code is inside another loop where r_b is changing so it takes a few minutes to run so I can measure time with a digital clock. When I specify the number of threads (with omp_set_num_threads) to 1 it runs faster compared to 2.

Comment: Try to divide the step's between the threads better. maybe you're doing the same work many times.

And also a tip: when you use clock() with openMP, it sums up the total clocks from all running threads, so if you have 4 threads, it will show result in 4 times more total clocks.

Comment: How can I divide the steps manually? Doesn't omp do this automatically?

Comment: it does if you say it to do, like in `#pragma omp parallel for` that the steps are divided between the threads.
But if you use only `#pragma omp parallel`, the exacty same code will run in all threads.

There are a loot of tools ( like pragma omp parallel ) that can divide the code / work between in more specific ways. Try to search about it on google.